# How to display a Message Box and get confirmation YES or NO from aspx.cs

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to dispaly a message box for confirmation to delete an Item or not but not sure how to do that if I use javascript alert, than how will I get confirmation??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`confirm`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) function:

```
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')) {
    // TODO : the user confirmed
}
```

As you've tagged your question with ASP.NET:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    ID="DeleteButton" 
    runat="server"
    CommandName="Delete" 
    Text="Delete"
    OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');" 
/>
```